# Error in reading image through OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting issues in reading an image using **opencv** in Python.Can someone please help??

What I had done??

Installed opencv in Anaconda and using jupyter notebook for running the code.I am using python3. **Below is the code:**

```
img =cv2.IMREAD("C:/Users/u266772/Desktop/Video/maddy.jpg",cv2.IMREAD.GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow ('image',img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**The error:**

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 img = cv2.IMREAD("C:/Users/u266772/Desktop/Video/maddy.jpg",cv2.IMREAD.GRAYSCALE)
>         2 
>         3 cv2.imshow ('image',img)
>         4 cv2.waitkey(0)
>         5 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
>
> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'IMREAD'

Comment: Use lowercase... cv2.imread

Comment: Thanks. Working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct usage is

```
img=cv2.imread('4.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

the imread function is lowercase. And its IMREAD_GRAYSCALE not '.'

Comment: If I run without cv2.waitkey(0),It's working...But if I use cv2.waitkey(0), again it's showing  "AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'waitkey' "

Comment: @MKumar its `cv2.waitKey(0)`, not `cv2.waitkey(0)`.

Comment: @Mkumar Great. Mark the answer as "Accepted" if your issue is resolved so that other users can know.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a case sensitive language.you used `IMREAD` function which is not a part of opencv. But for reading images you should use imread function.because of this you got that error.

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'IMREAD'.
```

And the last thing always see the type of error.and google it .after that you should post questions on forums to get an answer.good luck!!!!

Answer (score -1):

For 64 bit machines, `cv2.waitkey(0)` will throw an error.

Instead, you should use

```
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
```

The below code is working fine now:

```
img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/u266772/Desktop/Video/photo1.jpg",1)

cv2.imshow ('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You use `& 0xFF` only in assignment like `response = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF` Your usage is redundant